# Finding a generator $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Task: Find $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$, such that $(f)=(X^2-1,\space X^3+1)$.

My idea (is it correct?):

We want to generate $(X^2-1,\space X^3+1)$ by one function $f$. So I look for the common dividor (should it be the greatest?) of those 2 polynomials. As $X^3+1=(X+1)(X^2-X+1)$ and $X^2-1=(X-1)(X+1)$, I take $f(X)=X+1$.

And now I check:

$f(X^3)=X^3+1$ and $f(X^2-2)=X^2-1.$

So $X+1$ generates the same as $f)=(X^2-1,\space X^3+1)$.

Comment: Your method of checking is wrong: note, for example, that $f(X+2)$ is not in the ideal $(f)$.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Why don't you use the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: First, you need to show that $X+1\in(X^2-1,X^3+1)$, and then you need to show that $X^2-1,X^3+!\in (X+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X+1$ divides both $X^2-1$ and $X^3+1$, it is clear that the ideal generated by $X+1$ *contains* $I$, because every element in $(X^2-1,X^3+1)$ is divisible by $X+1$.

What is needed is the converse inclusion, which is equivalent to $X+1\in (X^2-1,X^3+1)$. (Why?)

In this case this is easy:
$$
(-X)\cdot(X^2-1)+1\cdot(X^3+1)=-X^3+X+X^3+1=X+1
$$

In general, you have to use the Euclidean algorithm.